Fetch ad account creation limit of meta business manager via API
I am currently working with the Meta Business Manager and the Facebook Graph API. In the Meta Business Manager UI, under Business Info, I can see a field labeled Ad account creation limit, which shows the maximum number of ad accounts that can be created for a particular business.
However, I am unable to find any relevant endpoint or field in the Facebook Graph API documentation that would allow me to fetch this information programmatically. I have searched through the available endpoints for businesses and ad accounts but haven’t found anything that matches.
Does anyone know if it's possible to retrieve the Ad account creation limit via the Facebook Graph API? If so, could you point me to the correct endpoint or provide an example of how to fetch this data?

